# How to display a div with onclick using javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Using javascript (no jquery) I want to target the articleContent div and make it appear after clicking a button with the div named "open" and then make it dissapear after clicking a div named "close" I have tried a bit but don't really know where to start and how to get it functioning.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
             <h1 class="h1"><img src="images/header2.PNG"/> </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id="navbar"> <b> <img src="images/home2.png" width="109" height="54"/> </b>
 <b><img src="images/about.png" width="l09" height="54"/> </b>
 <b><img src="images/news.png" width="109" height="54"/></b>
 <b><img src="images/contact.png" width="109" height="54"</b> 
            </div>
            <div id="article1" class="articleContent">
                <p class="font">This is the content</p>
                <p class="font"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">&copy;2014 | Privacy | Contact Information</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you think we need to see your `<header>` element? Where is the code you tried? What SO answer have you seen and explored that were not helpful? (There's dozens regarding this topic.)

Comment: What kind of element is *`clicking a button with the div named "open"`* and where is it in your code?

Answer (score 1):

supposing that you have divs with open and close ids, you can do this:

```
var article = document.getElementById('article1');
article.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('open').onclick= function(){
  article.style.display = 'block';
}
document.getElementById('close').onclick= function(){
 article.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript function. Example :

```
function open(){

 document.getElementById(one).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide (){
   document.getElementById(one).style.display = 'hide';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function open(e) {
    e.removeAttribute("style");
}

function close(e) {
    e.style.display = "none";
}
```

Call these functions with your buttons, passing the element that you wish to open/close.

`<button id="open" onclick="open(document.getElementById('article1'))" />`

`<button id="close" onclick="close(document.getElementById('article1'))" />`

Comment: I have bad feelings about this one. Wouldn't `open` and `close` interfere with some other code?

Comment: As long as you don't have any other methods with those name you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can track mouse click using onclick()=function(){//handle event}
see these links for more infos:
Event attributes section: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp
Mouse Events section: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Then you can set div display property using javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp
css dispay property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

```
  open=document.getElementById("openDiv");
  open.onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("articleContent").style.display=hidden;
  }
  hide=document.getElementById("hideDiv");
  hide.onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("articleContent").style.display=initial;
  }
```

I did'nt try it but i think it should work.
Good luck.

Comment: Many client side professionals generally don't like w3schools: http://www.w3fools.com/